# It it possible to define a mojo that takes a list of objects as a parameter?

Tags: maven-plugin

Reading up on the guide for developing maven plugins I see that you can define list parameters and arbitrary object parameters, but is it possible to define a parameter that id a list of objects, defined as:

```
/**
 * @parameter
 */
private List<MyObject> objects;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure - I do this all the time.  Make sure MyObject is a Java bean with each attribute annotated with @parameter, etc. just as you would if each parameter were in the Mojo itself.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't even annotate anything in MyObject, just list parameter.

```
@Parameter(property = "versioning.scripts")
private List<MyObject> scripts;
```

and all is working fine anyway.

Comment: is there anything more to do with the custom class? I'm currently trying to create a simple person class, like in http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Mapping_Complex_Objects but I always get the following error: Unable to parse configuration of mojo ... for parameter person: Cannot create instance of class ...$Person

Person class looks like this:
public class Person {
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
}

Comment: question solved: Person must not be an inner class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921848/maven-mojo-mapping-complex-objects?noredirect=1#comment63302174_37921848